# WiFi on Xubuntu is painfully slow. What is wrong, and what can I do?

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu, broadcom

I bought my PC for two weeks time ago, and it worked flawlessly. However, the last week my WiFi has been extremely slow (< 1kB/s) for some reason. I have absolutely no idea why this is; Ubuntu says that I'm connected to the internet, but trying to disconnect and reconnect sometimes makes it struggle.

Another thing that doesn't make much sense is that Wifi is just as fast as I'd hoped just when I boot my computer, but give it 5 minutes and it gets so slow. And after this I would have to restart my computer to hopefully get that sweet, sweet five minutes of fast internet back.

I realized that my network card ASUS PCE-AC56 (PCI-Express) is not officially supported for Linux, but it works with the driver I was suggested to install: `bcmwl-kernel-source`. The only other thing I had tried was editing the file `/etc/gai.conf` and uncommenting the

```
line precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

Because somebody said that it might help, but it didn't. Is there anything else I could try to do, so that the internet could get it's former speed back?

EDIT:
Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:85ba]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: It would also be helpful to specify the version of Xubuntu you're running -- 16.04?  17.04?  17.10 beta?  Something older?

Comment: Oh, of course. Yes, I run 16.04. :)